# max and min value of matching lines

Tags: awk, max, matching, min, lines

I would like to count min and max value of my matching line in file:

I have:

```
xxx 5
xxx 0  
xxx 10  
yyy 1  
yyy 5  
yyy 10
```

And I would like to have on output:

```
xxx 0 10
yyy 1 10
```

Minimum and maximum value for `xxx` and `yyy` matches.

My code is:

```
awk '{if(min==""){min=max=$2}
      if($2>max) {max=$2}
      if($2<min) {min=$2}
      n[$1]++}
      END {for (l in n) {print l "\t" min[l] }}' inputfile
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: So what's your error? Is there even an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need arrays for this:

```
awk '!($1 in min) {min[$1]=$2; max[$1]=$2}
     {max[$1]=(max[$1]<$2?$2:max[$1])
      min[$1]=(min[$1]>$2?$2:min[$1])}
      END { for (i in max) print i, min[i], max[i]}' file
```

#### Explanation

`max[]` contains the maximum value for each value. The same applies to `min[]`.

- `!($1 in min) {min[$1]=$2; max[$1]=$2}` if there is no `min` for current field, initialize them.
- `max[$1]=(max[$1]<$2?$2:max[$1])` if the current 2nd field is bigger than the corresponding maximum for the 1st column, replace.
- `min[$1]=(min[$1]>$2?$2:min[$1])` the same with the minimum.
- `END { for (i in max) print i, min[i], max[i]}` loop through the results and print them.

#### Test

```
$ awk '!($1 in min) {min[$1]=$2; max[$1]=$2} {max[$1]=(max[$1]<$2?$2:max[$1]); min[$1]=(min[$1]>$2?$2:min[$1])} END { for (i in max) print i, min[i], max[i]}' a
yyy 1 10
xxx 0 10
```

We need to define the min and max when reading the first line!

```
$ cat a
x -1
x 0
y 1
x -3
$ awk '!($1 in min) {min[$1]=$2; max[$1]=$2} {max[$1]=(max[$1]<$2?$2:max[$1]); min[$1]=(min[$1]>$2?$2:min[$1])} END { for (i in max) print i, min[i], max[i]}' a
x -3 0
y 1 1
```

Comment: Could also use `getline` if memory was constrained.

Comment: I don't think using `getline` is necessary here, @Jidder, how would you implement that? With arrays should be enough. There is a good paper by Ed Morton talking about it, cannot find it now.

Comment: Note also I updated my first answer it was a bit wrong.

Comment: @fedorqui Reading this again, no I don't think it is. To implement it though, for each new $1 it would read the file and find the min and max for that $1 and store them in temp variable in a function, then print, it could then skip all further of this $1. Its unnecessary complicated for this question though and i don't even know why i suggested it.

Comment: No problem, @Jidder! It is always good to rethink what we do and how we do. Thanks for commenting :)

Comment: @fedorqui I try the first your post and it works very good. The second one I have some weird output. Original was:  awk '{max[$4]=(max[$4]<$8?$8:max[$4]); min[$4]=(!(min[$4]) || min[$4]>$8?$8:min[$4])}END {for (i in max) print i "\t" min[i] "\t" max[i]}' input_file

Comment: @Incorigible yes, true, the first code was not correct. That's why I updated. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @fedorqui No I think the first code was right. The new one give me weird result :-( I just validate it..

Comment: @Incorigible strange... the second one is working fine to me for every sample input I use. By the way, you can always see the previous revisions in http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26236749/revisions

Comment: @fedorqui if 0 is the highest number then max will fail for the same reason that min would.

Comment: @Jidder no. `!(var)` is just true if `var` is not defined or it is `0`. You can test like this: write from -10 to 10 in a file: `seq -10 10 >a`. Check when the condition is accomplished: `awk '!$1 {print "it is empty or 0:", $1}' a`

Comment: I read it wrong(again! sorry) but the problem i experienced was cause by zero being the highest number as stated in the next comment. Thanks for the quick reply though :)

Comment: @Jidder sorry, I was referring to your previous comment. Regarding the zero you are right. I just updated, defining the values on the first read. Thanks!

Comment: @fedorqui Yeah I am sorry my fault.. The first code failed if my value is zero.. The new updated code works perfectly with 0 value (zero is my lowest value in my files).. Many thanks for your time and help! I learned something new!